# Wix - How to replace unstoppable driver

Tags: wix, driver

My product uses a driver that cannot be stopped. Because of this, deleting the associated service will mark the service for deletion but it won't be effective until reboot.

So, to create an installer and support upgrading, what should I add in the Wix project so, un upgrade, the old version is removed, then computer reboots and then installer continues with new version installation?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you said exactly how you install the driver, and if the driver and the service are the same thing. Normally you'd just add a ScheduleReboot action to the install.

Comment: Although not the best method, the .sys is copied to the app folder and a service is created using a custom action. On uninstall, another custom action deletes the service.

Comment: I hope you create batch files for both installing/uninstalling the services

Comment: May be. I'll take the idea as an alternative.

Comment: I had similar driver that is unstoppable, User dont want to reboot until his next scheduled weekly reboot. So is it possible to keep older driver running and replace new driver file.